# Twitter like multiple image upload using Blueimp Jquery File Upload Plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-file-upload, blueimp

I am using Blueimp's Jquery File Upload Plugin, I need a feature similar to twitter, in which user can choose 
1) "multiple" images,
2) "preview" before upload
3) Remove chosen image

First two points have been implemented. I want only one request so the the singleFileUploads option set to false in my code.

Problem:

When I set singleFileUploads to false, only one cancel button appears, clicking on it removes all the selected images.

I want remove/cancel button with every selected image preview. Clicking on it should remove only that image from queue.

Also, I want to do something when the remove button is clicked, is there any callback available?

Please Note :- Upload and everything is working fine, I just want to remove any selected image by clicking on remove button.

Answer (score 0):

I am using [Jquery Multifile](http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/multifile/) without a problem.

1. The plugin allows you to upload single file or even multiple files.
   Every batch of uploads are grouped and assigned a close button so you can only remove specific files.
2. The next nice feature is the preview of images.